# How to access a datsource via ssl in wildfly

Tags: ssl, wildfly

Does anybody know how to declare a datsource that can only be accessed via an ssl encrypted connection in wildfly?

In an existing client application this is done by declaring the connection URL accordingly (e.g. jdbc:hsqldb:hsqls://servername:4444/DBName) and adding a keystore with the certificate to the classpath.

I am new to wildfly and I could not find a possibility to declare a datasource accordingly in wildfly or a documentation how this could be done.

I am using ubuntu 14.04, wildfly 8.1 and java 8.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Best regards,
Lutz

Answer (score 2):

You need just configure your database to support SSL and provide proper connection-url in datasource (and add certificate to keystore). 
Here is mine example configuration to postgresl with SSL encrypted connection which I use:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/dbname" pool-name="poolname">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://serveraddress:5432/dbname?ssl=true</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>postgresql-jdbc41</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    </validation>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="postgresql-jdbc41" module="org.postgres">
        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

Comment: @Miksa apart from setting SSL true in the connection URL, don't we need to configure the certificates somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your feedback. Because I am currently working with a self signed certificate I had to add my certificate to the java keystore. After that it worked just fine. Saved my day :-) cheers, Lutz

Comment: which keystore did you add it to? I am having the same problem